# Drupal does not show site

Tags: database, updating

I have the following error on my drupal Site, **PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'filename' in 'field list': SELECT name, filename FROM {system} WHERE status = 1 AND bootstrap = 1 AND type = 'module' ORDER BY weight ASC, name ASC;**

It all started when one of the users of the Server tried to remove mysql installation files. The database is working correctly however it does not show the column in the table that the previous query tries to fetch.

I have already tried both to update-db from drush or to update the whole installation with no success.

I need some help please, I have thought to alter the table to include those columns but I don't know if that's actually a good idea.

Thank you

Comment: You need to add the below two lines in your php.ini file, which will be present in your root of your hosting directory.    extension=pdo.so  
    extension=pdo_mysql.so

Comment: @Bala how it is supposed to help, when he can already connect, and just fails for one column, not a whole table? user1210358, is this column really there when you use native MySQL clients to examine database? If no, restore it from last backup. Preferably, restore whole database from backup, really.